# React.js Vite TS app returns 404 when refreshed on route (only on the host not on the local) i tested it on render and vercel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, render, vite, vercel

whenever i refresh page except the home page it's gave me 404 only for host
i'm using vite +reactjs +ts

in vite config file i did that to do rewrite but it's not working

```
const rewriteSlashToIndexHtml = () => {
  return {
    name: 'rewrite-slash-to-index-html',
    apply: 'serve',
    enforce: 'post',
    configureServer(server) {
      // rewrite / as index.html
      server.middlewares.use('/', (req, _, next) => {
        if (req.url === '/') {
          req.url = '/index.html'
        }
        next()
      })
    },
  }
}
```

and used it here

```
const defaultConfig: DefaultConfig = {
  plugins: [
    react({ include: "**/*.tsx", }),
    rewriteSlashToIndexHtml()
  ],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'https://tame-lime-rooster-tie.cyclic.app',
        changeOrigin: true,
        configure: (proxy, options) => {
          proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, res) => {
            if (!req.headers.cookie) {
              return;
            }
            console.log('req.headers.cookie', req.headers.cookie)
            proxyReq.setHeader('cookie', req.headers.cookie);
          });
        },
        secure: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it didn't help me